# not able to save data from bootstrap form to data base in Django

Tags: python, django

I have created a form that takes 3 inputs from a user and saves user input to DataBase but I am not able to load data from the form to Sqlite dataBase there isn't any error shown on the screen but not able to store data in Db from the user input form.  Please Help me I am stuck in here from last 24 hours Thank you

views.py

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import EmployeeForm
from .models import Person


def index(request):
return render(request, 'base.html')


def employee(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.POST
    first_name = data['first_name']
    last_name = data['last_name']
    email = data['email']
    obj = Person.objects.create(
        first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email)
    if obj:
        return redirect('/')

    return HttpResponse("employee is not created")

else:
    person = Person.objects.all()

    context = {

        'person': person

    }

return render(request, 'employee/employee.html', context)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Person(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=110)
email = models.EmailField()
```

employee.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block main %}

<div class="context">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
Add new 
</button>
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">
Employee Details
</div>

</div>


</div>
<form method=="POST" >
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add New Employee</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    
   

<div class="form-group">
<label for="first_name">First Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="Enter name">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Enter name">

</div>



<div class="form-group">
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">

</div>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
{% endblock  %}
```

Project Urls.py

```
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.urls import path, include
 from employee.views import employee,index
 from employeer.views import employer


urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

path('',index),
path('employee',employee),
path('employeer',employer)
]
```

Comment: All your buttons have `type="button"`... I assume your button "_Save changes_" is supposed to submit the form? Change its type to submit i.e. `type="submit"`

Comment: Change its type to submit Data are not passed to the Data base

Comment: [08/Jun/2021 19:02:05] "GET /employee?csrfmiddlewaretoken=aBaG6F86qFa20h7D2ygp8qWh7yznJeBUxu58epsO2k0qhMQ2mqh9Go05NcFYpGg6&first_name=yhtyyhh&last_name=fggh&email=abc%40gmail.com HTTP/1.1" 200 3620                                                         But data are not shown in DB

Comment: Please show your url patterns. That should have been a POST request but it seems to be making a GET request instead?

Comment: from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from employee.views import employee,index
from employeer.views import employeer

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('',index),
    path('employee',employee),
    path('employeer',employeer)


]

Comment: Please don't post code / errors in the comment (very unreadable), [edit] your question instead.

Comment: Please Check the code I edit wuestion

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer :

Change this

```
<form method=="POST" >
```

to

```
<form method=="POST" action="{% url 'employee' %}" id="my-form">
```

and change your url pattern as

```
urlpatterns = 
[ path('admin/', admin.site.urls), 
  path('',index), 
  path('employee',employee,name='employee'), 
  path('employeer',employeer) ]
```

also

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
```

to

```
<button type="submit" form="my-form" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
```

Explanation :

1. You were submitting the form, but not telling where to send the `POST` request. so `action="{% url 'employee' %}"` this tells that where to submit form
2. You haven't provided the name to the url pointing to the `employee` view.
   This gives a name to url.

```
path('employee',employee,name='employee'),
```

Read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns)

Comment: It's not working data are not saved on the Db